# totally clear a modem module serial buffer during reading

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, modem

I have a gsm modem module, **first of all** I tried it from microcom appl. and everything was fine.
**Secondly** I implemented my own code in c. If I pass the AT commands I can read that and its answer many times. How I can clear the port? It seems sometimes I can read the port almost until forever. :-)

I tried not to consider that, but it causes confusion when I process the responses.

I use Linux.

Tamas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tcflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcflush.3.html) to flush the input, output, or both.

> tcflush() discards data written to the object referred to by fd but
>   not
>          transmitted, or data received but not read, depending on the value of
>          queue_selector:
>
> ```
>    TCIFLUSH
>           flushes data received but not read.
>
>    TCOFLUSH
>           flushes data written but not transmitted.
>
>    TCIOFLUSH
>           flushes both data received but not read, and data written but not
>           transmitted.
> ```

Comment: thanks, I knew there must be something similar to this :-)
Now I can make the buffer empty.